# Export CSS file content into TEXTAREA with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't find an answer anywhere for this annoying issue.

Do you know how can I drop a CSS file content (from an external link) into an HTML textarea with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what is being asked but I gather you wish to get a css file contents via ajax and put it in a textarea?

This is untested but I think it should work.

```
<body>
<input id="link" placeholder="link to css file" />
<button id="button" value="Fetch CSS">Fetch CSS</button>
<textarea id="textarea">CSS Content Will load here</textarea>
<script>
$('#button').click(function(){
  var link = $('#link').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: link,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(content){
        $('#textarea').val(content);
    }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This should work, unless `external link` means from another server/domain. Then ajax won't work.

Comment: yeah, If it is an `external link` then you will need to use an intermediate (e.g. `PHP CURL`) script on your own server to fetch the content and return it to your ajax request.